# building camera app on android

Tags: android, camera

hey there I'm new to app developing and I'm trying to build an app which includes the camera.
I followed the android developers guide and yet the app won't run, after trying to look for old answers in this site and not finding any that helped me, I'm asking for your help.
here's my code:

```
package com.example.camera;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.hardware.Camera;
import android.hardware.Camera.PictureCallback;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
public static final int MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE = 1;
public static String TAG="MainActivity";
private Camera camera;
private CameraPreview preview;
private PictureCallback picture;
private FileNotFoundException err;
public static Camera getCameraInstance(){
    Camera c = null;
    try {
        c = Camera.open(); // attempt to get a Camera insta
    }
    catch (Exception e){
        // Camera is not available (in use or does not exist)
    }
    return c; // returns null if camera is unavailable
}
private boolean checkCameraHardware(Context context) {
    if (context.getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA)){
        // this device has a camera
        return true;
    } else {
        // no camera on this device
        return false;
    }
}
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    camera = getCameraInstance();
    preview = new CameraPreview(this, camera);
    FrameLayout FLpreview = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.camera_preview);
    FLpreview.addView(preview);

    picture = new PictureCallback() {

        @Override
        public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {

            File pictureFile = getOutputMediaFile(MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE);
            if (pictureFile == null){
                Log.d(TAG, "Error creating media file, check storage permissions: "+ err.getMessage());
                return;
            }

            try {
                FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(pictureFile);
                fos.write(data);
                fos.close();
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                Log.d(TAG, "File not found: " + e.getMessage());
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Error accessing file: " + e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    };
    Button captureButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_capture);
    captureButton.setOnClickListener(
        new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // get an image from the camera
                camera.takePicture(null, null, picture);
            }
        }
    );
}
/** A safe way to get an instance of the Camera object. */


  private void releaseCamera(){
        if (camera != null){
            camera.release();        // release the camera for other applications
            camera = null;
        }
    }
  private static Uri getOutputMediaFileUri(int type){
      return Uri.fromFile(getOutputMediaFile(type));
}
  /** Create a File for saving an image or video */
  private static File getOutputMediaFile(int type){
      // To be safe, you should check that the SDCard is mounted
      // using Environment.getExternalStorageState() before doing this.

      File mediaStorageDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
                Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), "MyCameraApp");
      // This location works best if you want the created images to be shared
      // between applications and persist after your app has been uninstalled.

      // Create the storage directory if it does not exist
      if (! mediaStorageDir.exists()){
          if (! mediaStorageDir.mkdirs()){
              Log.d("MyCameraApp", "failed to create directory");
              return null;
          }
      }

      // Create a media file name
      String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
      File mediaFile;
      if (type == MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE){
          mediaFile = new File(mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator +
          "IMG_"+ timeStamp + ".jpg");

      } else {
          return null;
      }

      return mediaFile;
  }

}
```

and here's the code for the surfaceholder:

```
package com.example.camera;

import java.io.IOException;

import android.content.Context;
import android.hardware.Camera;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
import android.view.SurfaceView;

public class CameraPreview extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {
private SurfaceHolder holder;
private Camera camera;
public static String TAG="MainActivity";
public CameraPreview(Context context, Camera cam) {
    super(context);
    camera=cam;
    holder=getHolder();
    holder.addCallback(this);
    holder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
}
public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
// The Surface has been created, now tell the camera where to draw the preview.
try {
    camera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);
    camera.startPreview();
} catch (IOException e) {
    Log.d(TAG, "Error setting camera preview: " + e.getMessage());
}
}
public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int w, int h) {
// If your preview can change or rotate, take care of those events here.
// Make sure to stop the preview before resizing or reformatting it.

if (holder.getSurface() == null){
  // preview surface does not exist
  return;
}

// stop preview before making changes
try {
    camera.stopPreview();
} catch (Exception e){
  // ignore: tried to stop a non-existent preview
}

// set preview size and make any resize, rotate or
// reformatting changes here

// start preview with new settings
try {
    camera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);
    camera.setDisplayOrientation(0);
    camera.startPreview();

} catch (Exception e){
    Log.d(TAG, "Error starting camera preview: " + e.getMessage());
}
}
public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
// empty. Take care of releasing the Camera preview in your activity.
}


}
```

and lastly, Logcat:

```
07-31 12:06:06.361: W/Camera(998): ICamera died
07-31 12:06:06.361: W/Camera(998): Camera server died!
07-31 12:06:06.381: E/Camera(998): Error 100
```

Thanks a bunch!

Comment: Why not start with something more simple if you are still new to programming?

Comment: a. I'm not new to programming, I'm new to android developing, sorry if that wasn't clear.
b. I like challenging myself.
c. It's a part of a project I'm working on.
thankyou:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to getCameraInstance() a bit later, e.g.  onStart()